# Using kernel density estimation to solve regression problem and don't know where to find literature

Tags: statistical-inference, machine-learning, regression

I am researching on a regression problem and have an idea like this:

Given training data $T=\{(x_1,y_1),\ldots,(x_N,y_N)\}$ and a validating point $x^*$, using a parameterized kernel function to get the distribution of $y^*$:

$$p(y^*|T,x^*) \propto \sum_{i=1}^N k_\theta(x_i-x^*,y_i-y^*)$$

and then optimize $\theta$ (maybe defined as a neural network) to maximize this probability over a validating dataset.

Are there any papers similar to this idea? I have read some Gaussian Process Regression and Kernel Density Estimation papers but find their methods are somewhat different from my idea. (but I'm not very familiar with GPs so I am not sure...)

Any suggestions? (Maybe some keywords I can GoogleScholar with)

Answer (score 1):

I think your idea is similar in spirit to [kernel regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_regression) (also known as the Nadaraya–Watson model).
Bishop offers a probabilistic treatment of the model in [his textbook](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/uploads/prod/2006/01/Bishop-Pattern-Recognition-and-Machine-Learning-2006.pdf%7D), §6.3.1.
More exactly, he shows that you can use a density estimation model for the *joint* distribution of inputs $\mathbf{x}$ and targets $y$:
$$
p(\mathbf{x}, y) = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^N f(\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{x}_i, y - y_i).
$$
Then the conditional distribution takes the form you indicated (since $p(y|\mathbf{x}) \propto p(\mathbf{x}, y)$) and the mean of the conditional distribution will be
$$
\mathsf{E}[y|\mathbf{x}] = \sum_{i=1}^N k(\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{x}_i) y_i
$$
with the kernel $k$ being derived from the density function $f$.

A usual choice of kernel is the zero-mean isotropic Gaussian,
but, as you suggest, more recent work has explored learning parameterized kernels,
a common parameterization being in terms of the [Mahalanobis metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahalanobis_distance)
[[1](http://proceedings.mlr.press/v2/weinberger07a/weinberger07a.pdf),
[2](https://papers.nips.cc/paper/6839-generative-local-metric-learning-for-kernel-regression.pdf)].

Another related line of work is locally weighed learning;
see [this survey](http://www.qou.edu/ar/sciResearch/pdf/distanceLearning/locallyWeighted.pdf) and maybe §6.3 from [Elements of Statistical Learning](https://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/ElemStatLearn/).